# INSERT INTO query WITH RECURSIVE query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a WITH RECURSIVE function and would like to use it with an INSERT INTO function so that the results insert into the path column.

| category_id | category_name | parent_id | path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Root | 0 |  |
| 2 | Fishing | 1 |  |
| 3 | Sea | 2 |  |
| 4 | Lures | 3 |  |
| 7 | Coarse | 2 |  |
| 8 | Lures | 7 |  |
| 9 | Fly | 2 |  |

I have tried the following code but the results do not fall in line with the table.

```
INSERT INTO categories (path)

WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT category_id, category_name, parent_id, category_name path
         FROM categories
         WHERE parent_id = 0
       UNION ALL
         SELECT c.category_id, c.category_name, c.parent_id, CONCAT(cte.path, '/', c.category_name)
         FROM categories c
         JOIN cte ON cte.category_id = c.parent_id 
       )
SELECT path FROM cte;
```

| category_id | category_name | parent_id | path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Root | 0 |  |
| 2 | Fishing | 1 |  |
| 3 | Sea | 2 |  |
| 4 | Lures | 3 |  |
| 7 | Coarse | 2 |  |
| 8 | Lures | 7 |  |
| 9 | Fly | 2 |  |
| null | null | null | Root |
| null | null | null | Root/Fishing |
| null | null | null | Root/Fishing/Sea |
| null | null | null | Root/Fishing/Coarse |
| null | null | null | Root/Fishing/Fly |
| null | null | null | Root/Fishing/Sea/Lures |
| null | null | null | Root/Fishing/Coarse/Lures |

I have the code in a db fiddle
[db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5m6kyCp7Qqdvp2RDZkurKA/2)

Comment: INSERT creates new rows. You probably want to use UPDATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rd5fxvWiFAEWnF5649MEh9/0) is my executed code.

```
UPDATE categories ca  
       inner join ( WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT category_id, category_name, parent_id, category_name path
         FROM categories
         WHERE parent_id = 0
       UNION ALL
         SELECT c.category_id, c.category_name, c.parent_id, CONCAT(cte.path, '/', c.category_name)
         FROM categories c
         JOIN cte ON cte.category_id = c.parent_id 
       )
                   select * from cte
       ) t on ca.category_id = t.category_id 
SET ca.path = t.path ;

SELECT * FROM categories;
```